# Image download failing after server upgrade

Tags: php, apache

I recently migrated to new ubuntu server with apache 2.4.7 and php 5.5.9. 
The code below is working fine on the old server running on ubuntu with apache 2.2.22 and php 5.3.10. but not on the new server.

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type:image/jpeg");
    echo './images/img1.jpg';   
?>
```

I am clueless why this is happening. Is there some apache config that I need to change/enable to make the above code work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some .htaccess "`Allow from`" directives in it?
They have changed in 2.4, they are called "`Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`" now.
See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html